# Should "while loops" be preferred to "for loops" for large, necessary loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Realizing that loops are usually not ideal in R, sometimes they are necessary.

When writing large loops, doesn't

```
for (i in 1:large_number)
```

waste memory, since a vector of size large_number must be created?

Would this make while loops the best choice for large, necessary loops?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, a lot of that 'loops are bad' chatter stems from the dark ages when loops where in fact less efficiently implemented, in particular in some versions of S-Plus.

That said, and while your comment about the need for a large index object is correct, you could also use

- functions from the `apply` family such as `sapply`, `lapply` or `tapply` to unroll your structures
- the relatively new [iterators](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/index.html) package which also avoids the large vector you mentioned as a memory constraint
- the [Ra 'accelerated R' variant and its jit package](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/) which can significantly accelerate simple loops.

As added bonus, options one and two give a path towards parallel execution of the loops on suitable systems using tools from the CRAN packages snow, multicore, or NWS just to name a few.

Comment: Dirk, I read recently a paper by Ihaka & Lang ("Back to the Future: Lisp as a Base for a Statistical Computing System)", in which R loops compared unfavorably to Python's. They both are slow compared to CLOS. I am asking around if R will become "not unlike" a functional language. What's your take??

Comment: No added insight here, sorry.  On the one hand you have the large user base of R and the need for backwards compatibility, on the other you the desire to experiment with new features. I think changes will only be evolutionary, not revolutionary.